# Transform arma::cube subview into NumericVector to use sugar

Tags: c++, rcpp, armadillo

I pass a 3D array from R into C++ and ran into type conversion issues. How do we transform `arma::cube subviews` from RcppArmadillo into `NumericVectors` to operate on them using sugar functions from Rcpp like `which_min`?

Say you have a 3D cube `Q` with some numeric entries. My goal is to get the index of the minimum value of the column entries for each row `i` and for each third dimension `k`.  In R syntax this is `which.min(Q[i,,k])`.

For example for `i = 1` and `k = 1`

```
cube Q = randu<cube>(3,3,3);
which_min(Q.slice(1).row(1)); // this fails
```

I thought a conversion to NumericVector would do the trick, but this conversion fails

```
which_min(as<NumericVector>(Q.slice(1).row(1))); // conversion failed
```

How can I get this to work? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

1. You can just use the Armadillo function for this, the member function `.index_min()` (see Armadillo documentation [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#index_min_and_index_max_member)).
2. You can use `Rcpp::wrap()`, which ["transforms an arbitrary object into a SEXP"](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) to turn the `arma::cube subviews` into a `Rcpp::NumericVector` and use the sugar function `Rcpp::which_min()`.

Initially I just had the first option there as the answer since it seems a more straightforward way to accomplish your objective, but I add the second option (in an update to the answer) since I now consider that arbitrary conversions may be a part of what you're curious about.

I put the following C++ code in a file `so-answer.cpp`:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List index_min_test() {
    arma::cube Q = arma::randu<arma::cube>(3, 3, 3);
    int whichmin = Q.slice(1).row(1).index_min();
    Rcpp::List result = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("Q") = Q,
                                           Rcpp::Named("whichmin") = whichmin);
    return result;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List which_min_test() {
    arma::cube Q = arma::randu<arma::cube>(3, 3, 3);
    Rcpp::NumericVector x = Rcpp::wrap(Q.slice(1).row(1));
    int whichmin = Rcpp::which_min(x);
    Rcpp::List result = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("Q") = Q,
                                           Rcpp::Named("whichmin") = whichmin);
    return result;
}
```

We have one function that uses Armadillo's `.index_min()` and one that uses `Rcpp::wrap()` to enable the use of `Rcpp::which_min()`.

Then I use `Rcpp::sourceCpp()` to compile it, make the functions available to R, and demonstrate calling them with a couple of different seeds:

```r
Rcpp::sourceCpp("so-answer.cpp")
set.seed(1)
arma <- index_min_test()
set.seed(1)
wrap <- which_min_test()
arma$Q[2, , 2]
#> [1] 0.2059746 0.3841037 0.7176185
wrap$Q[2, , 2]
#> [1] 0.2059746 0.3841037 0.7176185
arma$whichmin
#> [1] 0
wrap$whichmin
#> [1] 0
set.seed(2)
arma <- index_min_test()
set.seed(2)
wrap <- which_min_test()
arma$Q[2, , 2]
#> [1] 0.5526741 0.1808201 0.9763985
wrap$Q[2, , 2]
#> [1] 0.5526741 0.1808201 0.9763985
arma$whichmin
#> [1] 1
wrap$whichmin
#> [1] 1
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(arma = index_min_test(), wrap = which_min_test())
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval cld
#>  arma 12.981 13.7105 15.09386 14.1970 14.9920 62.907   100   a
#>  wrap 13.636 14.3490 15.66753 14.7405 15.5415 64.189   100   a
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you for both! The conversion code was what I wanted to know in the general case. I didn't know about .index_min() -- sweet, works like a charm.

Comment: @JBJ No problem, glad it helped! Cheers